# postgresql installation warning about FLEX

Tags: postgresql

configuring postgresql 9.1.6 to install, I get message like bellow...

```
checking for flex... configure: WARNING:
*** The installed version of Flex, /usr/bin/flex, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Flex version 2.5.31 or later is required, but this is /usr/bin/flex version 2.5.4.
configure: WARNING:
*** The installed version of Flex, /usr/bin/lex, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Flex version 2.5.31 or later is required, but this is /usr/bin/lex version 2.5.4.
configure: WARNING:
*** The installed version of Flex, /usr/bin/flex, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Flex version 2.5.31 or later is required, but this is /usr/bin/flex version 2.5.4.
configure: WARNING:
*** The installed version of Flex, /usr/bin/lex, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Flex version 2.5.31 or later is required, but this is /usr/bin/lex version 2.5.4.
configure: WARNING:
*** The installed version of Flex, /usr/bin/flex, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Flex version 2.5.31 or later is required, but this is /usr/bin/flex version 2.5.4.
configure: WARNING:
*** The installed version of Flex, /usr/bin/lex, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Flex version 2.5.31 or later is required, but this is /usr/bin/lex version 2.5.4.
no
configure: WARNING:
*** Without Flex you will not be able to build PostgreSQL from Git nor
*** change any of the scanner definition files.  You can obtain Flex from
*** a GNU mirror site.  (If you are using the official distribution of
*** PostgreSQL then you do not need to worry about this because the Flex
*** output is pre-generated.)
```

it says "If you are using the official distribution of PostgreSQL~~~" downloaded file is from  postgresql official site, then can it be ignor

Comment: Configuring it on *what version* of *what operating system*? As for the "can be ignored": If the build succeeds despite the warnings, everything is fine. It'll only fail if you're building a copy of Pg from git, not a release source tarball. The release source tarballs will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is raised because you do not have flex installed, which is used in part to generate the SQL language parser.  The release tarballs already have the SQL language parser generated so you are ok if you are using a release tarball.  If you want to build from git, or you want to change how SQL is parsed (or SQL syntax) then you need to get flex.

In most cases, this warning can be ignored if you don't know otherwise (I am assuming if you are trying to modify the PostgreSQL source in ways that matter here you do know otherwise).  if you can't build, use a release tarball.

Comment: If Flex isn't installed then why did it find version 2.5.4?

"*** Flex version 2.5.31 or later is required, but this is /usr/bin/flex version 2.5.4."

I get the same warning when I install Pg from source on CentOS 5.9.